# Firebase transaction triggers function error?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

Already spent quite a few hours trying to figure out the following, hopefully someone could point me.

In short what's happening: I have a firebase function that basically updates a database value in a transaction. But if I use transaction, the function always fail with this error:

```
Unhandled error RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
    at Function.isNull
```

Even though the transaction correctly updates the value in the database.

I was trying to debug it and remove anything I can. So whenever I remove transaction and use `update()` for example, the function finishes as expected with code 200.

As soon as I put transaction back the function fails with the following stacktrace:

```
Unhandled error RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
    at Function.isNull (/user_code/node_modules/firebase-functions/node_modules/lodash/lodash.js:11950:20)
    at encode (/user_code/node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/providers/https.js:217:11)
    at /user_code/node_modules/firebase-functions/node_modules/lodash/lodash.js:13402:38
    at /user_code/node_modules/firebase-functions/node_modules/lodash/lodash.js:4911:15
    at baseForOwn (/user_code/node_modules/firebase-functions/node_modules/lodash/lodash.js:2996:24)
    at Function.mapValues (/user_code/node_modules/firebase-functions/node_modules/lodash/lodash.js:13401:7)
    at encode (/user_code/node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/providers/https.js:242:18)
    at /user_code/node_modules/firebase-functions/node_modules/lodash/lodash.js:13402:38
    at /user_code/node_modules/firebase-functions/node_modules/lodash/lodash.js:4911:15
    at baseForOwn (/user_code/node_modules/firebase-functions/node_modules/lodash/lodash.js:2996:24)
    at Function.mapValues (/user_code/node_modules/firebase-functions/node_modules/lodash/lodash.js:13401:7)
```

Another similar stacktrace I've got:

```
Unhandled error RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
    at /user_code/node_modules/firebase-functions/node_modules/lodash/lodash.js:13402:38
    at /user_code/node_modules/firebase-functions/node_modules/lodash/lodash.js:4911:15
    at baseForOwn (/user_code/node_modules/firebase-functions/node_modules/lodash/lodash.js:2996:24)
    at Function.mapValues (/user_code/node_modules/firebase-functions/node_modules/lodash/lodash.js:13401:7)
    at encode (/user_code/node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/providers/https.js:242:18)
    at /user_code/node_modules/firebase-functions/node_modules/lodash/lodash.js:13402:38
    at /user_code/node_modules/firebase-functions/node_modules/lodash/lodash.js:4911:15
    at baseForOwn (/user_code/node_modules/firebase-functions/node_modules/lodash/lodash.js:2996:24)
    at Function.mapValues (/user_code/node_modules/firebase-functions/node_modules/lodash/lodash.js:13401:7)
    at encode (/user_code/node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/providers/https.js:242:18)
```

Here is the function:

**index.js:**

```
    const statsModule = require("./stats")

    exports.myMethod9 = functions.https.onCall((data, context) => {
        console.log("updateStatsMessagesChangedFeedbackHttp: data = ", data)
        return statsModule.updateStatsMessagesChangedFeedbackHttp(data, context, admin);
    });
```

**stats.js**

```
exports.updateStatsMessagesChangedFeedbackHttp = function (data, context, admin) {
    var userId = "sdfsdf";
    var feedback = data.feedback;
    console.log("updateStatsMessagesChangedFeedbackHttp: userId = ", userId)
    return exports.updateStatsMessagesChangedFeedback(userId, feedback, admin);
}

exports.updateStatsMessagesChangedFeedback = function (userId, feedback, admin) {
    console.log("updateStatsMessagesChangedFeedback: feedback = ", feedback, ", userId = ", userId);

    var root = admin.database().ref().root;
    var path = constModule.statsUpdatedMessagesFeedbackPath + "/" + feedback;
    var statsRef = root.child(path);
    return statsRef.transaction(function (stats) {
        if(!stats) {
            stats = {votedUsers:{}, count: 0};
        }
        stats.votedUsers[userId] = true;
        console.log("updateStatsMessagesChangedFeedback: stats = ", stats)
        return stats;
    }, function (error, committed, snapshot) {
        //nothing wrong here - error is always null, committed - true

        var snapVal = snapshot ? snapshot.val() : null;
        console.log("error = ", error, ", committed = ", committed, ", data = ", snapVal);
        if (error) {
            // The fetch succeeded, but the update failed.
            console.error("updateStatsMessagesChangedFeedback: The fetch succeeded, but the update failed: ", error);
        } else {
            console.log("updateStatsMessagesChangedFeedback: all ok: data = ", snapVal);
        }
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
        //this is never called - all good here as well
        console.error("updateStatsMessagesChangedFeedback: error = ", error)
    });
}
```

I call it from client web sdk like this:

```
var call = firebase.functions().httpsCallable('myMethod9');dFeedbackHttp
call({feedback: "some data"}).then(function (result) {...})
```

Neither catch, nor the transaction callback shows any errors. Though the function still fails only if I use transaction.

[image]
(click the image to enlarge)

Any ides on what's going on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After discussion with support (very helpful guys by the way!) here is the solution:

one need to return a value from function in case of transaction:

```
 exports.myMethod9 = functions.https.onCall((data, context) => {
        console.log("updateStatsMessagesChangedFeedbackHttp: data = ", data)
        return statsModule.updateStatsMessagesChangedFeedbackHttp(data, context, admin);
    }).then(function(){
        return {}
    });
```

I don't have any clue on why returning a value makes any difference here as for example update() returns void which still makes the function complete with code 200.

Waiting on further comments form the support and meanwhile if anyone has any info on this feel free to share.